# Find first element of certain type in a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What would be the shortest notation to find the first item that is of a certain type in a list of elements using LINQ and C#.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var first = yourCollection.OfType<YourType>().First();
```

Note that the [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) method will throw an exception if there are no elements of type `YourType`. If you don't want that then you could use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) or [`Take(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) instead, depending on the behaviour you do want.

Answer (score 15):

Use the OfType extension method:

```
public static T FindFirstOfType<T>(IEnumerable list){
 return list.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: this IEnumerable list to make it an extension?

Answer (score 8):

You want [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
list.OfType<MyType>().First();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the `FirstOrDefault` and pass in the delegate to use for the comparison.

```
object[] list = new object[] {
    4,
    "something",
    3,
    false,
    "other"
};

string first = list.FirstOrDefault(o => o is string); //something
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Because the `FirstOrDefault` is returning an `object` and you have to cast it to `string` for it to be assigned to the first variable declared as `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [hugoware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322767/2591755)'s answer, to avoid unnecessary iterations:

```cs
(string)source.FirstOrDefault(f => f is string)
```

---

But if you worry about micro optimizations, you could create your own extension method:

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IList source)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            if (source[i] is T)
                return (T)source[i];
        }
            
        return default;
    }
}
```

Benchmarks using a 100 objects lists where only the last one is a string (dotnet 7, [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)):

```cs
[Benchmark]
public string OfType_First() => objects.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault();

[Benchmark]
public string FirstOrDefault() => (string)objects.FirstOrDefault(f => f is string);

[Benchmark]
public string FirstOrDefault_T() => objects.FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

```
|           Method | Size |       Mean |    Error |    StdDev | Allocated |
|----------------- |----- |-----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|
|     OfType_First |  100 | 1,229.0 ns | 57.86 ns | 157.41 ns |      96 B |
|   FirstOrDefault |  100 |   920.1 ns | 18.31 ns |  31.59 ns |      40 B |
| FirstOrDefault_T |  100 |   671.4 ns | 12.24 ns |  15.91 ns |         - |

// * Legends *
  Size      : Value of the 'Size' parameter
  Mean      : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error     : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev    : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Median    : Value separating the higher half of all measurements (50th percentile)
  Allocated : Allocated memory per single operation (managed only, inclusive, 1KB = 1024B)
  1 ns      : 1 Nanosecond (0.000000001 sec)
```